# What time window size the Eurocontrol's IFPS considers when comparing the EET informed by the airline and its own calculated EET?

Tags: flight-planning

Excerpt from IFPS Users Manual Ed. 22.0 (chapter 34. PROFILE CALCULATION/ROUTE ANALYSIS):

```
In addition, whenever present in a message, the estimated elapsed time(s) 
(EET) shall be used by the IFPS for profile calculation, together with the 
total elapsed time (Item 16B). Prior to using the EET information, the IFPS 
shall validate it against its own calculated EETs allowing for the provided 
EETs to be within a pre-defined window around the EETs as calculated by the 
IFPS. In the case the provided EET information is found to be outside this 
window, the message shall not be invalidated. In this case the IFPS shall 
retain its own calculated EETs.
```

What is the size of the aforementioned pre-defined window?

Comment: This window is expressed as a percentage. I read a [French tutorial about CFMU](https://ecitydoc.com/download/ifps-pilote_pdf), which may still help, in which error PROF 191 was issued as "*PROF191: TTL_EET DIFFERENCE > 40%, CALCULATED TTL_EET FROM LFRS TO LFLB = 0101 (HHMM)*", making me believe this could be 40%.